# Power Query: Unpivoting Multiple different Attributes at the same time

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

In Power BI's Power Query, let say I have the below table.

| Customer | Product 1: Type | Product 1: Cost | Product 2: Type | Product 2: Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cust 1 | A | $5 | B | $15 |
| Cust 2 | A | $5 | C | $20 |

The goal is to unpivot so that there is no product 1 or product 2, just product, effectively taking the 4 columns in to 2

| Customer | Product Type | Product Cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cust 1 | A | $5 |
| Cust 1 | B | $15 |
| Cust 2 | A | $5 |
| Cust 2 | C | $20 |

I know this is fairly simple if just unpivoting from many columns to 1 column through the Unpivot columns function.
But how do you go about unpivoting many columns into n columns without doing this n times and rejoining?

Comment: Is the line `Cust 1 B $1` correct?

Comment: No it was a typo. Thank you for point out.
This is all sample data anyway, more to show an simplified example of what I am working with

Comment: and did any of these answers help you?

Answer (score 1):

You can unpivot all columns except `Customer`, split the `Attribute` values into `Product` and `Header`, then re-pivot:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45Wci4tLlEwVNJRcgRiFVMg4QRiGJoqxepAZY2QZZ1BDCMDpdhYAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Customer = _t, #"Product 1: Type" = _t, #"Product 1: Cost" = _t, #"Product 2: Type" = _t, #"Product 2: Cost" = _t]),
    Unpivoted = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Customer"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Split Attribute" = Table.SplitColumn(Unpivoted, "Attribute", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({": "}, QuoteStyle.Csv, false), {"Product", "Header"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Split Attribute", List.Distinct(#"Split Attribute"[Header]), "Header", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"Product"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

Which turns

[image]

into

[image]

Comment: After some tweaks this worked perfectly. You are the man Olly. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This should work also

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
base_columns=1, groupsof=2, // stack them
Combo = List.Transform(List.Split(List.Skip(Table.ColumnNames(Source),base_columns),groupsof), each List.FirstN(Table.ColumnNames(Source),base_columns) & _),
#"Added Custom" =List.Accumulate(
    Combo, 
    #table({"Column1"}, {}),
    (state,current)=> state & Table.Skip(Table.DemoteHeaders(Table.SelectColumns(Source, current)),1))
in #"Added Custom"
```

[image]